# How to properly use Observables, @Binding, and @Published

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm working on the creation of an iPhone application and am having a few issues with the nature of @Binding, @ObservedObject, and the @Published property. I was pretty sure I have this all right but apparently not since it's still not working.

Here is a "minimal" example of what's happening -- if I reduce the layers of nesting views, then it starts working correctly.

```
import SwiftUI

//character
class TopLevelParent: ObservableObject  {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    @Published var prop: [Child1] = [Child1(), Child1(), Child1()]
}

class TestState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tlp: TopLevelParent = TopLevelParent()
}

//level
class Child1: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    @Published var prop: [Child2] = [Child2(), Child2()]
}

//levelskill
class Child2: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    @Published var clicked: Int = 0
    @Published var maxClick: Int = 3
    @Published var prop: [YoungestChild] = [YoungestChild(), YoungestChild(), YoungestChild(), YoungestChild(), YoungestChild()]
}

//skill
class YoungestChild: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    @Published var name: String = "name"
    @Published var hasIncreased: Bool = false
}

struct TestView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var state: TestState
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(state.tlp.prop, id:\.id) { prop in
                        NavigationLink(destination: TestView2(testclass2: prop)) {
                            VStack {
                                TestView5(testclass2: prop)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestView2: View {
    @ObservedObject var testclass2: Child1
    @State private var activeSkillBonus: UUID?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
            let testclass3 = testclass2.prop
            VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach(testclass3) { index in
                    TestView3(testclass3: index, activeSkillBonuses: $activeSkillBonus)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



struct TestView3: View {
    @ObservedObject var testclass3: Child2
    @Binding var activeSkillBonuses: UUID?
    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading)
        {
            VStack {
                Text("Skill Boosts - \(testclass3.clicked)/\(testclass3.maxClick)")
                Text("\(testclass3.id)")
            }
            .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .foregroundStyle(Color.oxblood))
            .onTapGesture{
                withAnimation {
                    if activeSkillBonuses == testclass3.id {
                        activeSkillBonuses = nil
                    } else {
                        activeSkillBonuses = testclass3.id
                    }
                }
            }
            if activeSkillBonuses == testclass3.id  {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(testclass3.prop) { index in
                        TestView4(testclass4: index, testclass3: testclass3)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestView4: View {
    @ObservedObject var testclass4: YoungestChild
    @ObservedObject var testclass3: Child2
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(testclass4.name)
            }
        }
        .foregroundStyle(testclass4.hasIncreased ? Color.red : Color.primary)
        .background(testclass4.hasIncreased ? Color.green : Color.brown)
        .onTapGesture {
            testclass3.objectWillChange.send()
            if testclass4.hasIncreased {
                testclass3.clicked -= 1
            } else
            {
                testclass3.clicked += 1
            }
            testclass4.hasIncreased.toggle()
        }
    }
}

struct TestView5: View {
    @ObservedObject var testclass2: Child1
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(testclass2.prop) {testclass3 in
                Text("Skill Bonus - \(testclass3.clicked)/\(testclass3.maxClick)")
            }
        }
    }
}
    
struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
            .environmentObject(TestState())
    }
}
```

Any idea why the `TopLevelParent.Child1[x].Child2[y].YoungestChild` value isn't propagating from TestView4 to TestView5?

Essentially, TestView1 is the "Top level" view, and has a set of TestView5's, one for each set of TopLevelParent.prop, set in a NagivationStack. When one of the TestView5's in the NavigationStack is pressed, it opens a view that has TestView2, which shows a TestView3 for each Child1.Prop, and in each TestView3, it has a TestView4 for each Child2.Prop (or Child2.YoungestChild) that can be pressed, which updates a value for Child2, which value is being displayed in TestView3, as well as in TestView5. TestView3 updates with the value correctly, but TestView5 remains at the starting value (0/3 pressed).

Comment: Try to just use a «var level» in LevelView. If the level is modified in the character object it will be propagated and redraw the view.

Comment: Unfortunately, that also didn't work. It looks like the issue is that the HomeView isn't being redrawn for some reason -- I added a `Text("\(character.levels[0].appliedSkill![0].skillsUsed)")` line in HomeView to see if it was updating, and it is also staying at 0, so it's an issue directly between HomeView and LevelUpView it appears.

Comment: Don't pass 'level.wrappedValue` to `LevelView` pass `level` and make the required changes to the declaration of `var level` in `LevelView`

Comment: In order to do that, best of my understanding, I need to set the `level` in `LevelView` to a `@Binding` instead of `@ObservedObject`, correct? I tried that but it is still not propagating the value, and still does not address the issue from my other comment, that the value doesn't appear to be getting sent to the `HomeView` anyways somehow.

Comment: The problem is more likely in your data objects than your views. `@Published` on an array doesn't publish is a property on an object in the array changes, for example. Perhaps try and create a [mcve]; you have a lot going on here.

Comment: Binding is for value types Level is a reference type it doesn’t work with Binding

Comment: @Paulw11 I've edited the question to have a "minimal" example -- as noted, if I reduce the layers of nesting, then it starts propagating correctly. I've also added an answer that works below, but I'm not sure that it's, you know, good practice or design to do it this way, and I'm open to hearing about modifications or better options. Thanks for the help so far!

Answer (score 0):

**Use one source of truth:**

Make sure there's one source of truth for your data. This often means having your data owned by a top level view or a shared `EnvironmentObject`.

Here's an example how you can demonstrate this:

- first create a `CharacterViewModel` that holds the `Character` and applies different actions on it or the `levels` in it:

```swift
@MainActor class CharacterViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var character: Character

    init(character: Character) {
        self.character = character
    }

    // Add methods to modify character and levels here
}
```

- initialize the view model on a top level view, and pass it to child views using `.environmentObject()`:

```swift
struct HomeView: View {
    @StateObject private var charVM = CharacterViewModel(character: Character())
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationStack {
                CharacterSummaryView(character: charVM)
                List($charVM.character.levels, id: \.levelNum) { level in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: LevelUpView(level: level)
                            .environmentObject(charVM)
                    ) {
                        VStack {
                            LevelView(level: level.wrappedValue)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- use the environment object in a child view:

```swift
struct LevelUpView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var charVM: CharacterViewModel

    // ...
}
```

- but, as long as you do not use the `Character` directly in `LevelUpView` and not in `SkillBoostsView` either, then you wouldn't even declare it there. Instead, you'd use it directly in `SkillPillboxView`:

```swift
struct SkillPillboxView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var charVM: CharacterViewModel

    // ...
    
    // Computed property to calculate the skill level
    private var skillLevelCalc: Int {
        return skillLevel(for: skill.name.rawValue,
                          in: charVM.character,
                          level: level)
    }

    // ...
    
}
```

> And so on...
> You'd probably want to store a property named `currentLevel` in `CharacterViewModel` to get rid of the rest `level` parameters you're passing to children (and also declare charVM in `LevelUpView` and `SkillBoostsView` for this, or use another view model, or find another solution that fits your needs).

This separation also ensures your code is clean and easy to debug by removing a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: This seems like a good approach that I should probably be taking overall, but unfortunately it did not help in this case. I've edited the original question to be more explicit on a minimal code example, and I'll also add an answer below for what I eventually got working which is probably not great practice but is working for now.

Answer (score 0):

If I update Child1 and Child2 with these changes, the code starts to work, and the value gets propagated to TestView5:

```
//level
class Child1: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    @Published var prop: [Child2] = [] {
        didSet {
            for child in prop {
                child.parent = self
            }
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        self.prop = [Child2(), Child2()]
        for child in prop {
            child.parent = self
        }
    }
}


//levelskill
class Child2: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    weak var parent: Child1?
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    @Published var clicked: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            parent?.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
    @Published var maxClick: Int = 3
    @Published var prop: [YoungestChild] = [YoungestChild(), YoungestChild(), YoungestChild(), YoungestChild(), YoungestChild()]
}
```

ChatGPT explains this:

> The issue is that TestView5 is not aware of changes made to Child2.clicked within TestView4 because TestView5 is observing Child1, which in turn contains an array of Child2. The @Published property wrapper only handles changes made directly to its wrapped value. When you modify a property within one of the Child2 objects, the Child1 object doesn't know about this change because the array reference itself hasn't changed, just one of the items within it.

Which makes sense, but I'm not sure if that's the real reason because we all know that ChatGPT is not entirely reliable all the time. In any case, I have it working for now (but am absolutely open to improvements on the code)

Comment: As ChatGPT told you, published property events don't propagate up/out. so `TopLevelParent.Child1[x].Child2[y].YoungestChild` doesn't work.  I think the proper solution is to design an appropriate model object so that the business logic is encapsulated in it at the top level.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not really sure how to better my design. Essentially, I need to be able to calculate the number of `YoungestChild.WasClicked` at each `Child1` (in this case, `TopLevelParent` is the character for a TTRPG character creation app, and `Child1` is each level in advancement) So I need to be able to calculate the score taking into account every level before the one I'm accessing whenever it's pressed, but exclude ones after, so there's not really a reasonable way for me to store the data in the Character/TopLevelParent unless I were to have 20x fields that also have 16-40 items.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I approached the problem.  It is similar to the approach suggested by Pierre.

The top level `Character` object has a function to modify skill boosts.  This function finds its way to the required object and updates it. Since that update can be denied (too many skill boosts), the lowest level `toggleBoost` function returns a boolean indicating whether or not it did anything.

This boolean value is used on the way back out to have the various observable objects send an `objectWillChange` event.

I use the environment so that each object doesn't need to be explicitly passed to each view.

**Models**

```swift
class TestState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var character: Character = Character(name:"Bilbo")
}

//character
class Character: ObservableObject  {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    @Published var levels: [Level] = [Level(name:"Level 1"), Level(name:"Level 2"), Level(name:"Level 3")]
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    
    @discardableResult
    func toggleBoost(level: Level, levelSkill: LevelSkill, skill: Skill) -> Bool {
        guard let level = self.levels.first(where:{ $0.id == level.id}) else {
            return false
        }
        
        let didToggle = level.toggleBoost(levelSkill: levelSkill, skill: skill)
        if didToggle {
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
        return didToggle
    }
}

//level
class Level: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    @Published var levelSkills: [LevelSkill] = [LevelSkill(name:"Level Skill 1"), LevelSkill(name:"Level SKill 2")]
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    
    func toggleBoost(levelSkill: LevelSkill, skill: Skill) -> Bool {
        guard let levelSkill = levelSkills.first(where:{ $0.id == levelSkill.id }) else {
            return false
        }
        
        let didToggle =  levelSkill.toggleBoost(skill: skill)
        if didToggle {
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
        return didToggle
    }
}

//levelskill
class LevelSkill: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    @Published var boostCount = 0
    let maxBoost: Int
    var name: String
    @Published var skills: [Skill] = [Skill(name:"Skill 1"), Skill(name:"Skill 2"), Skill(name:"Skill 3"), Skill(name:"Skill 4"), Skill(name:"Skill 5")]
    init(name: String, maxBoost:Int = 3) {
        self.name=name
        self.maxBoost = maxBoost
    }
    
    func toggleBoost(skill: Skill) -> Bool {
        if let skill = self.skills.first(where: {$0.id == skill.id}) {
            if (!skill.hasIncreased && self.boostCount < self.maxBoost) || skill.hasIncreased {
                skill.hasIncreased.toggle()
                self.setBoostCount()
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
    
    private func setBoostCount() {
        self.boostCount = self.skills.reduce(0,{ $1.hasIncreased ? $0+1:$0})
    }
}

//skill
class Skill: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    @Published var hasIncreased: Bool = false
    var name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

**Views**

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var state: TestState
    
    var body: some View {
        CharacterView(character: state.character)
    }
}

struct CharacterView: View {
    @ObservedObject var character: Character
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(self.character.levels) { level in
                        NavigationLink(destination: CharacterDetailView(level: level).environmentObject(self.character)) {
                            VStack {
                                LevelView(level: level)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CharacterDetailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var character: Character
    var level: Level
    @State private var activeSkillBonus: UUID?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
            let testclass3 = level.levelSkills
            VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach(testclass3) { index in
                    SkillBoostView(levelSkill: index, activeSkillBonuses: $activeSkillBonus).environmentObject(self.level)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



struct SkillBoostView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var character: Character
    @EnvironmentObject var level: Level
    @ObservedObject var levelSkill: LevelSkill
    @Binding var activeSkillBonuses: UUID?
    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading)
        {
            VStack {
                Text("Skill Boosts - \(levelSkill.boostCount)/\(levelSkill.maxBoost)")
                Text("\(levelSkill.id)")
            }
            .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .foregroundStyle(Color.red))
            .onTapGesture{
                withAnimation {
                    if activeSkillBonuses == levelSkill.id {
                        activeSkillBonuses = nil
                    } else {
                        activeSkillBonuses = levelSkill.id
                    }
                }
            }
            if activeSkillBonuses == levelSkill.id  {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(levelSkill.skills) { skill in
                        SkillBonusView(skill:skill).environmentObject(self.levelSkill)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SkillBonusView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var character: Character
    @EnvironmentObject var level: Level
    @EnvironmentObject var levelSkill: LevelSkill
    @ObservedObject var skill: Skill
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(skill.name)
            }
        }
        .foregroundStyle(skill.hasIncreased ? Color.red : Color.primary)
        .background(skill.hasIncreased ? Color.green : Color.brown)
        .onTapGesture {
            self.character.toggleBoost(level: level, levelSkill: levelSkill, skill: skill)
        }
    }
}

struct LevelView: View {
    @ObservedObject var level: Level
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(level.levelSkills) { levelSkill in
                Text("Skill Bonus - \(levelSkill.name) \(levelSkill.boostCount)/\(levelSkill.maxBoost)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```